# Why does the interpreter hang when evaluating the expression?

Tags: python

Here's my experiment:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Feb 19 2014, 13:47:28) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = 3
>>> while True:
...   a = a * a
... 
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
KeyboardInterrupt
>>> a
(seems to go on forever)
```

I understand that the interpreter looped forever at the "while True: " part, but why did it get stuck evaluating `a`?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof(a)` > 443212 or some similarly large number. Welcome to the world of exponents!

Comment: it doesnt go on forever ... however python supports very very large numbers ...  it can take quite a while to print very long strings ... a very large number is just a very long string when you print it to the screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a` is now a really large number and it takes a while to print. Print `a` in the loop and you'll see it gets really big, this is just a fraction of how large it is if you omit the print, because print takes time to execute. Also, note `a=1` always quickly returns `1`.

Comment: To be a little more specific, it's not the *printing* which is slow, it's the conversion of the integer to a string.

Comment: @DSM actually it is both! First the conversion _then_ the printing.